# Inject commands to crontab -e?

Tags: scripting, cron, io-redirection, here-document

Edit: I use Debian stable 9.3.

I have the following code which is aimed to run inside root's crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /opt/cron_daily.sh
0 0 * * 0 /opt/cron.weekly.sh
```

Of course I can manually copy it, then execute `crontab -e`, then pasting it in the end of the file, but what if I want to insert/inject/print this code into the root's crontab **from a command** instead?

Is it possible with an heredocument or some other technique?

Note: I must use `crontab` and not `/etc/cron` which as I know, are two different things.

### Update

If it matters somehow, I load the two cron scripts daily_cron.sh and weekly_cron.sh from heredocuments in Github (I copy them and paste and execute them directly in terminal).

Please show how to inject each script to daily and weekly crontabs.

Comment: Stephen, I wrote them myself... muru, of course it's just for the sake of testing, without m, h, dom, month, dok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add those to cron, you could do the following:

```
echo '0 0 * * * /opt/cron_daily.sh
0 0 * * 0 /opt/cron.weekly.sh' | sudo crontab
```

Answer (score 4):

Working on the assumption that you use Debian or derivatives, I recommend dropping the scripts in `/etc/cron.daily` and `/etc/cron.weekly` instead. Basically:

```
... > /etc/cron.daily/your_daily_script
... > /etc/cron.weekly/your_weekly_script
chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/your_daily_script /etc/cron.weekly/your_weekly_script
```

with better names for the scripts of course (based on their purpose rather than their intended frequency).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I guess it's best to give `.sh` as an ending and to add a scrip declaration (for example `#!/bin/sh` or it doesn't matter in that case?

Comment: If you give them a `.sh` extension, they’ll be ignored (`run-parts`, which is used to process `/etc/cron.{daily,weekly}`, ignores files containing periods by default). Specifying the shebang in a shell script is always a good idea.